# How to change the timezone in Cassandra to eastern standard time?

Tags: cassandra, nosql, timezone

I have created a cqlshrc file and I have changed the timezone but whenever I update the `timestamp` column in my table. It still displays UTC time

```
;; Display timezone
timezone = America/New_York
```

Comment: did you also uncomment the `[ui]` line?

Comment: yes It is uncommented I even tested it by turning color off and it worked but timezone does not seem to work @AlexOtt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not have the `pytz` module installed all i had to was run this command:

```
sudo easy_install --upgrade pytz
```

and then the changes made to the timezone in the config file applied